# Android+maven to a simple android project?

Tags: android, maven

I have an android project with maven having all these dependencies, I want to "export" it (or whatever it is called) to a simple project, meaning I don't want to use maven anymore, and have all jars inside `libs` folder, is there anyway I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: please if you downvote at least say something !

Comment: If you "have all jars inside `libs` folder", what is the problem?

Comment: I don't have that yet, that's what I want to achieve, I don't want to use maven's dependencies anymore